# Microsoft Orleans maximum grains per silo

Tags: configuration, distributed-computing, orleans

I am testing [Microsoft Orleans](https://github.com/dotnet/Orleans) for feasibility as a distributed computing framework. It seems like it may work however I was wondering how do I set the maximum number of active grains in a given silo?

My grains will not purely be CPU bound and will perform some IO and other related tasks. I am worried that if I let it run wild it will spin up a massive number of instances which will bog the whole thing down.

Is silo configuration like this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Orleans is very well suited for non-CPU-bound work. Orleans grains are designed to use `Task<T>` for asynchrony instead of threads, so you should always perform asynchronous IO, using C#'s [async/await][1] feature.

If you absolutely need to perform blocking IO, you can perform the IO outside the context of the grain and `await` the result in your grain, like so:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => {
  // Perform blocking work.
  return 43;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to offload all blocking operations to Thread Pool and keep MaxActiveThreads at default (#cores).
Basically you never want to block Orleans threads (those MaxActiveThreads). Those Orleans thread should do a light compute and issue external async calls (to other grains or external services). all heavy compute should be done not on Orlean's threads.

You can do that and still maintain single threaded execution guarantees.
See here: https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/grains/external_tasks_and_grains.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Silo configuration xml file has that configuration ability.

```
<Scheduler MaxActiveThreads="15"/>
```

The XSD for it is specified [online](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/Orleans/Configuration/OrleansConfiguration.xsd).